# Index Of Row To Copy Is Out Of Range

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

Ill start off with my code and then explain the problem.

```
 var customerAddresses = new CustDeliveryAddresses();

        // Select Columns
        customerAddresses.Query.Columns.Add(new Column(CustDeliveryAddress.FIELD_DESCRIPTION));
        customerAddresses.Query.Columns.Add(new Column(CustDeliveryAddress.FIELD_POSTCODE));

        // Filter by Customer.
        customerAddresses.Query.Filters.Add(new Filter(CustDeliveryAddress.FIELD_CUSTOMERDBKEY, customerLookup.Customer.SLCustomerAccount));

        // Find
        customerAddresses.Find();


        var addresses = from CustDeliveryAddress address in customerAddresses
                        select new
                        {
                            address.Description,
                            address.PostCode
                        };

        //customerDeliveryAddesses.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        customerDeliveryAddesses.DataSource = addresses.ToList();
```

So, when addresses.ToList() is assigned to the DataSource property of the DataGridView (customerDeliveryAddresses) i get an error stating "Index of row to copy is out of range" and I cant for the life in me find out why.

Please could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could it be multiple enumeration issue? Anyone?

Comment: I suspect the error is coming from something else we're not seeing.  Maybe something in the definition of `customerDeliverAddresses` itself?  When *exactly* is the error thrown?  When you call `addresses.ToList()`?  When you set it to the data source?  When the UI renders?  Some other time?

Comment: @David it throws the exception when i set the datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i feel a little stupid now.

For some reason I had put code which sets the DataSource to null when the selected index changes.

yeah i know, why? answer is, i dont know why i did that :P but remove it, and all is ok